# Splitting string in 2 parts by removing substring in golang

Tags: string, go, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse strings that look something like this:

`abc***********xyz`

into a slice (or 2 variables) of "abc" and "xyz", removing all the asterisks.

The number of `*` can be variable and so can the letters on each side, so it's not necessarily a fixed length. I'm wondering if go has a nice way of doing this with the strings package?

Comment: I'd scan from the start & end until you hit an asterisk - then you know the sub-string indices. So a simple for-loop would be way more efficient to do this than any `strings` or `rexexp` function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [strings.FieldsFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#FieldsFunc) where `*` is a field separator.

```
s := "abc***********xyz"
z := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool { return r == '*' })
fmt.Println(len(z), z)  // prints 2 [abc xyz]
```

[Live Example](https://go.dev/play/p/Ak1ABUD9vbB).

Answer (score 1):

Split on any number of asterisks:

```
words := regexp.MustCompile(`\*+`).Split(str, -1)
```

See [live demo](https://go.dev/play/p/kDuH8Pu_U83).

Answer (score 0):

if performance is an issue, you can use this func:

```
func SplitAsteriks(s string) (result []string) {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return
    }

    i1, i2 := 0, 0

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == '*' && i1 == 0 {
            i1 = i
        }
        if s[len(s)-i-1] == '*' && i2 == 0 {
            i2 = len(s) - i
        }
        if i1 > 0 && i2 > 0 {
            result = append(result, s[:i1], s[i2:])
            return
        }
    }

    result = append(result, s)
    return
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/L56oSQ8N40B)

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, write a for loop:

```
func SplitAsteriks(s string) []string {
    var (
        in     bool     // true if inside a token
        tokens []string // collect function result here
        i      int
    )
    for j, r := range s {
        if r == '*' {
            if in {
                // transition from token to separator
                tokens = append(tokens, s[i:j])
                in = false
            }
        } else {
            if !in {
                // transition from one or more separators to token
                i = j
                in = true
            }
        }
    }
    if in {
        tokens = append(tokens, s[i:])
    }
    return tokens
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SfkTAwhFx4b).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code given that the string is specified to have two parts:

```
s := "abc***********xyz"
p := s[:strings.IndexByte(s, '*')]
q := s[strings.LastIndexByte(s, '*')+1:]
fmt.Println(p, q) // prints abc xyz
```